# List of enum values in java

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to create ArrayList of enum values (and manipulate it)? For example:

```
enum MyEnum
{
   ONE, TWO
}

MyEnum my = MyEnum.ONE;
List <?> al = new ArrayList <?>();
al.add(my);
al.remove(al.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible, but you will have to do

```
List<MyEnum> al = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
```

You can then add elements to `al`: `al.add(ONE)` or `al.add(TWO)`.

Comment: This returns an empty list for me.

Comment: @BasilBourque It depends on the interpretation of the question. I made a clarifying edit.

Answer (score 152):

You can simply write

```
new ArrayList<MyEnum>(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()));
```

Answer (score 45):

## tl;dr

Can you make and edit a collection of objects from an enum? **Yes.**

If you do not care about the order, use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html), an implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html).

```
enum Animal{ DOG , CAT , BIRD , BAT ; }

Set<Animal> flyingAnimals = EnumSet.of( BIRD , BAT );

Set<Animal> featheredFlyingAnimals = flyingAnimals.clone().remove( BAT ) ;
```

If you care about order, use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) implementation such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). For example, we can create a list of a person’s preference in choosing a pet, in the order of their most preferred.

```
List< Animal > favoritePets = new ArrayList<>() ;
favoritePets.add( CAT ) ;  // This person prefers cats over dogs…
favoritePets.add( DOG ) ;  // …but would accept either.
                           // This person would not accept a bird nor a bat.
```

For a non-modifiable ordered list, use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)).

```
List< Animal > favoritePets = List.of( CAT , DOG ) ;  // This person prefers cats over dogs, but would accept either. This person would not accept a bird nor a bat.
```

## Details

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109543/642706) (`EnumSet`) by Amit Deshpande and [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109656/642706) (`.values`) by Marko Topolnik are both correct. Here is a bit more info.

## `Enum.values`

The `.values()` method is an *implicitly declared method* on [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), added by the compiler. It produces a crude array rather than a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). Certainly usable.

Special note about documentation: Being unusual as an *implicitly declared method*, the `.values()` method is *not* listed among the methods on the `Enum` class. The method is [defined in the *Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), and is mentioned in the doc for [`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-).

## `EnumSet` – Fast & Small

The upsides to [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) include:

- Extreme speed.
- Compact use of memory.

To quote the class doc:

> Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if their argument is also an enum set.

Given this enum:

```
enum Animal
{
    DOG , CAT , BIRD , BAT ;
}
```

Make an `EnumSet` in one line.

```
Set<Animal> allAnimals = EnumSet.allOf( Animal.class );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "allAnimals : " + allAnimals );
```

> allAnimals : [DOG, CAT, BIRD, BAT]

Make a set from a subset of the enum objects.

```
Set<Animal> flyingAnimals = EnumSet.of( BIRD , BAT );
```

Look at [the class doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to see many ways to manipulate the collection including adding or removing elements.

```
Set<Animal> featheredFlyingAnimals = 
    EnumSet.copyOf( flyingAnimals ).remove( BAT );
```

## Natural Order

The doc promises the Iterator for EnumSet is in natural order, the order in which the values of the enum were originally declared.

To quote the class doc:

> The iterator returned by the iterator method traverses the elements in their natural order (the order in which the enum constants are declared).

Frankly, given this promise, I'm confused why this is not a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). But, oh well, good enough. We can create a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) from the `Set` if desired. Pass any `Collection` to constructor of `ArrayList` and that collection’s [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is automatically called on your behalf.

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>( allAnimals );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println("list : " + list );
```

When run.

```
list : [DOG, CAT, BIRD, BAT]
```

In Java 10 and later, you can conveniently create a non-modifiable `List` by passing the `EnumSet`. The order of the new list will be in the iterator order of the `EnumSet`. The iterator order of an `EnumSet` is the order in which the element objects of the enum were defined on that enum.

```
List< Animal > nonModList = List.copyOf( allAnimals ) ;  // Or pass Animals.values()
```

Comment: Great insight in this answer!

Comment: Hey!
I created arraylist based on enum. Now, I want to get user input and store it in that array. But its not allowing to add.

Comment: @Snoke You should post a carefully written Question that shows your code, stripped down to the minimum amount of code needed to show your issue. Contrive a simple example as I did here with my four animals.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible but you should use [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead

```
enum MyEnum {
    ONE, TWO;
    public static final EnumSet<MyEnum> all = EnumSet.of(ONE, TWO);
}
```

Comment: Why should an `EnumSet` be used? What if the OP wants an ordered list?

Comment: Yeah, will try EnumSet, but just curious about ArrayList.

Comment: @A.R.S. Elements in `EnumSet` are in natural order. Check the java doc

Comment: @AmitD Yes but there is no way to order them differently than their natural order, as there is with `ArrayList`.

Comment: EnumSet is also a Set and therefore cannot contain duplicate items.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is the maintenance. I now have 2 sets of lists to maintain - one in the enum definition and one in the set definition. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is just another class in Java, it should be possible.

More accurately, an enum is an instance of Object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

So yes, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ONE, TWO;
    
    public List<MyEnum> getEnumValues(){
        return new ArrayList<MyEnum>(Arrays.asList(values()));
    }
}
```

And you can access this as:

```
List<MyEnum> theValues = MyEnum.getEnumValues();

//Iterate through it.. 
for(MyEnum e : theValues){
    System.out.println(e.name); 
}
```

Output:

```
ONE
TWO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic solution, that can be use for any Enum object, so be free of used.

```
static public List<Object> constFromEnumToList(Class enumType) {
    List<Object> nueva = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (enumType.isEnum()) {
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(enumType.getCanonicalName());
            Object[] consts = cls.getEnumConstants();
            nueva.addAll(Arrays.asList(consts));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se localizo la clase");
        }
    }
    return nueva;
}
```

Now you must call this way:

```
constFromEnumToList(MiEnum.class);
```

Comment: This is incredibly over-complicated and doesn't provide any type protection (part of the reason the `enum` type was added to Java).

Comment: I think enum.values() is a much easier approach to get a Collection of your enums.

Comment: booo reflection