# How to properly use Enums for simple price calculation (Java)

Tags: java, list, enums, hashmap

I am trying to optimize a code-snippet that looks like this:

```
public class Kvarteret {
    public static final String ONE_BEER = "hansa";
    public static final String ONE_CIDER = "grans";
    public static final String REAL_BEER = "vestkyst";
    public static final String GT = "gt";
    public static final String BACARDI_SPECIAL = "bacardi_special";

    public int calculatePrice(String drink, boolean student, int amount) {

        if (amount > 2 && (drink == GT || drink == BACARDI_SPECIAL)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Too many drinks, max 2.");
        }

        int price;

        if (drink.equals(ONE_BEER)) { price = 74;}
        else if (drink.equals(ONE_CIDER)) { price = 103;}
        else if (drink.equals(REAL_BEER)) { price = 110; }
        else if (drink.equals(GT)) { price = ingredient6() + ingredient5() + ingredient4();}
        else if (drink.equals(BACARDI_SPECIAL)) {
            price = ingredient6()/2 + ingredient1() + ingredient2() + ingredient3();
        } else { throw new RuntimeException("Item not in menu"); }

        if (student && (drink == ONE_BEER || drink == ONE_CIDER || drink == REAL_BEER)) { price = price - price/10;}
        return price*amount;
    }

    //rom unit
    private int ingredient1() { return 65;}

    // grenadine unit
    private int ingredient2() { return 10;}

    //lime-juice unit
    private int ingredient3() { return 10;}

    //mint-leafs unit
    private int ingredient4() { return 10; }

    //tonic-water unit
    private int ingredient5() { return 20; }

    //gin unit
    private int ingredient6() { return 85; }
}
```

The code is a simple program that calculates the price of drinks. I used [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186756/simple-barista-application-to-calculate-the-price-of-a-drink-based-on-different) code as a starting point because it seemed like they we're trying to do something similar.

My code so far looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Kvarteret2 {
    private static double price;
    private static double order;

    // Enums defines common values
    private enum Beer_Cider {
        BEER("Hansa", 74), CIDER("Grans", 103), REAL_BEER("Vestkyst", 110);

        private static String order;

        Beer_Cider(String order, double cost) {
            order = order;
            price = cost;
        }

        private static String getOrder() {return order;}
        private static double getCost() {return price;}
    }

    private enum DrinkIngredients {

        ROM("Rom", 65), GRENADINE("Grenadine", 10), LIME("Lime-juice", 10),
        MINT("Mint", 10), TONIC("Tonic-water", 20), GIN("Gin", 85);

        private static String ingredient;

        DrinkIngredients(String ingredient, double cost){
            ingredient = ingredient;
            price = cost;
        }

        private static String getIngredient() {return ingredient;}
        private static double getCost() {return price;}
    }

    // Dictionary with the drink as Key and a list of the ingredients and prices as value
    Map<String, List<DrinkIngredients>> Drinks = new HashMap<String, List<DrinkIngredients>>(); 

    public Kvarteret2() {
        Drinks.put("GT", [DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT]);

    }


    private static double calculate_price(String drink, boolean student, int amount){

        if (amount > 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many drinks! You can order max 2 drinks at a time.");
        }

        double student_discount = 0.1;

        if (student){
            if (drink == "BEER" || drink == "CIDER" || drink == "REAL BEER") {
                price = amount * (price - price * student_discount);
            }
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error because of this code:

```
public Kvarteret2() {
    Drinks.put("GT", [DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT]);

}
```

I am trying to add elements to the dictionary, but I dont think this is the right way to do it.

I know my code might not be 100% optimized yet, but I just want to see if I can make this solution work before I try to make it even better (because there's most likely a better way to do this).

How do I properly create the dictionary I am trying to create using the enums?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of enum values in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109497/list-of-enum-values-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

You are using an incorrect syntax for creating a *list* in Java (*it doesn't work in the same way as in JavaScript*):

```
[DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT] // <- that's not correct

List.of(DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT) // <- correct
```

Enum-fields that has to be associated with a specific enum-constant should not be marked `static`. Modifier `static` indicates that a field is shared among all the instances of a class, `enum`s at the end of the day are classes. If you want string `order` to be unique for all kinds of drinks, this line is not correct:

```
private static String order;
```

Another mistake in the constructor:

```
Beer_Cider(String order, double cost) {
    order = order;
    price = cost;
}
```

Line `order = order;` will not work as you expect. It will not assign the object property, instead it just reassigns parameter `order` to itself. You should use the keyword [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) to refer to the object field order.

```
private enum BeerCider {
    BEER("Hansa", 74), CIDER("Grans", 103), REAL_BEER("Vestkyst", 110);
    
    private String order;
    private double cost;
    
    Beer_Cider(String order, double cost) {
        this.order = order;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    
    private String getOrder() {return order;}
    private double getCost() {return cost;}
}
```

*For more information of *enums* have a look at* [*this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

*Sidenote:* according to [*Java naming conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) underscore should be used only the names of constants (like unum-members, `static final` fields), but the name of an  `enum` has to be written in camel-case `BeerCider`, like names of classes and interfaces.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, since the factory method List.of() is available only from Java 9, you can create a list from an array: Arrays.asList(DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT), or alternatively from a Stream: Stream.of(DrinkIngredients.GIN, DrinkIngredients.TONIC, DrinkIngredients.MINT).collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 1):

Though you haven't mentioned what error you got, but this is how you can populate your `Kvarteret2` constructor:

```
// Dictionary with the drink as Key and a list of the ingredients and prices as value
    Map<String, List<DrinkIngredients>> Drinks = new HashMap<String, List<DrinkIngredients>>(); 
   List<DrinkIngredients> list=new ArrayList<DrinkIngredients>(); // define ArrayList outside constructor

public Kvarteret2() {
  list.add(DrinkIngredients.GIN);
  list.add(DrinkIngredients.TONIC);
  list.add(DrinkIngredients.MINT);
  Drinks.put("GT", ls);
}
```